# How to get XRender man pages on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, manpage

```
$ man XRenderFillRectangle
No manual entry for XRenderFillRectangle
```

I already have thees packages installed: xorg-docs-core libx11-doc libx11-dev libxrender-dev

Comment: This question appears to be off topic but would be great on the sister site [AskUbuntu.](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need someone to write man pages.   libXrender currently doesn't have any man pages written, only the incomplete API doc at http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libXrender/tree/doc/libXrender.txt.